# Bash: execute a command with quotes using a function

Tags: bash

I have a generic function which executes a given command, prints its output to the console and returns the command's output in the same time:

```
# Command execution
# Executes a given command, redirect stdout to stderr, prints output and returns exit code
# Function arguments:
#   - $1: the command to be executed
cmd_exec() {
    cmd=$1

    exec 5>&2
    echo "Executing command '$cmd' ..."
    output=`"${cmd[@]}" 2>&1 |tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`
    status=$?
    echo "Command exited with status code: $status"
    echo

    echo "$output"

    echo
    return $status
}

backup_cmd=(sudo -u postgres sh -c '/usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -Fc database > /path/to/file')

cmd_exec $backup_cmd
status=$?
if [ "$status" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Error during backup!"
fi
```

When I execute the command I see that only the command `sudo` is executed and this is because I'm getting the `sudo` help output:

```
Executing command 'sudo' ...
Command exited with status code: 1

usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
```

**Note:** I wrote the `cmd_exec` generic function because I need to send the output of the command to both stdout and stderr because I want its output to be printed on the console during the execution without waiting the execution to finish.

Comment: Use `cmd_exec "$backup_cmd"` instead?

Comment: I get the same: `Executing command 'sudo' ...`

Comment: Change it to
`backup_cmd=$(sudo -u postgres sh -c '/usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -Fc database > /path/to/file')`

Comment: @bobdylan now no command is executed: `Executing command '' ...
Command exited with status code: 127

/usr/local/sbin/generic-functions.sh: line 94: : command not found`

Comment: That's obviously an error relating to a different script. The command is now executing though. Change it to `backup_cmd=$(sudo -u postgres sh -c 'echo 1')` and you'll see the echo being output

Comment: @bobdylan: `Executing command '1' ...
Command exited with status code: 127

/usr/local/sbin/generic-functions.sh: line 94: 1: command not found`

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @bobdylan this way the `cmd_exec` function is executing the output of `sudo -u postgres sh -c 'echo 1'` (which is `1`). This is not correct because I need to pass the command, not its output. The commands has to be executed by `cmd_exec`, not by the main script.

Comment: @mat - without seeing your full script it's impossible to know what line 94 is. Either way - it's not getting the 'sudo error' which is what you've asked

Comment: @bobdylan - `generic-functions.sh` contains some other functions, line 94 is the line `output=`"${cmd[@]}" 2>&1 |tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`` from the `cmd_exec` function. The sudo error is because the main script is not passing the complete command to the `cmd_exec` function, not for an error in the command

Comment: What about calling `su - postgres -c 'echo 1'` (instead of `sudo -u postgres sh -c 'echo 1'`)?

Answer (score 0):

When you assign this array:

`backup_cmd=(sudo -u postgres sh -c '/usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -Fc database > /path/to/file')`

You don’t want to pass it like that to your function:

`cmd_exec $backup_cmd`

In this case, only the first element of the array will be passed, i.e. `sudo`.

You should pass the array elements as double-quoted expansion:

`cmd_exec "${backup_cmd[@]}"`

There’s no need to store parameters to your local variable `cmd` in your function, you may use the function parameters as `$@` instead:

```
# Command execution
# Executes a given command, redirect stdout to stderr, prints output and returns exit code
# Function arguments:
#   - $@: the command to be executed along with its arguments
cmd_exec() {
    exec 5>&2
    echo "Executing command '$cmd' ..."
    output=`"$@" 2>&1 |tee /dev/fd/5; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`
    status=$?
    echo "Command exited with status code: $status"
    echo

    echo "$output"

    echo
    return $status
}
```

Please note that variables will *not* be expanded in single-quoted arguments. In other words, if you want to set the arguments optional like this:

`backup_cmd=(sudo -u postgres sh -c '$pgdump -U $username -Fc $database > $filename')`

You need to use double quotes instead:

`backup_cmd=(sudo -u postgres sh -c "$pgdump -U $username -Fc $database > $filename")`

Comment: Thanks! What if I need to improve the function to add a new parameter to specify if I want the output to be printed or not? In another function I use `$2`which can be `0=never print | 1=always print | 2=print only on error`?

Comment: Because you have an indefinite number of parameters, any parameter you want to add must be added beforehand. e.g. `cmd_exec 1 "${backup_cmd[@]}"`and then in your function you fetch the argument before shifting: `cmd_exec(){ local option=$1; shift; #at this point $@ contains all parameters but the first one; }`

Comment: Now, strange problem: `Executing command 'sudo -u postgres sh -c $pgdump -U $backup_user -Fc $db > $file' ...
Command exited with status code: 127

sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
sh: 1: -U: not found`

Comment: @Mat it looks like the quoted arguments have been lost. Did you call `cmd_exec "${backup_cmd[@]}"` or `cmd_exec ${backup_cmd[@]}` (without double quotes)?

Comment: I'm calling `cmd_exec "${backup_cmd[@]}"`

Comment: It may also be the consequence that `$pgdump` is a variable that is not carried over `sudo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208490/discussion-between-mat-and-vdavid).

Comment: Now variables are correctly expanded, but redirection seems not working, because I'm getting the output of pg_dump and the file is not written on the given path..